# Compare current time with an epoch date integer

Tags: sql, date, db2, epoch

An Epoch date integer includes year, month, day, hour, min and seconds when it is converted to "human date", but how can I compare epoch time with a specific time of the day (Ex: 13:45)

In other words, if I get the epoch date from a program as an integer number and I want to write a program that checks if that epoch time is after 13:45 of that same day, what would be the logic to do this?

I have the epoch date in a dabatase field and a specific time (13:45) in another field and I need to check if it is 13:45 or later every time I check the current date. I am using DB2, but it doesn;t really matter because I want to understand the logic (mathematically if possible) of comparing time vs whole epoch date and see if it matches.

Thank you

Comment: DB2 lacks many of the utilities you'd need to do this easily.  Hopefully your application layer has an applicable library - I'd recommend not hitting the database anyways.  As Matt's answer points out, dealing with date and time is rather involved.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by "epoch date" you mean a [unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (which is UTC based), then logically:

1. Interpret the integer unix timestamp as a date and time in UTC.
2. Convert from UTC to the applicable time zone.
3. Take the date from step 2 and pair it with the time of day in question.
4. Ensure that the new date and time of day are *valid* in the chosen time zone, and disambiguate if there is more than one interpretation.  This is important for values near daylight saving time transitions.  See [the DST tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info) for more details.
5. Convert the local date and time from step 3, and any adjustment determined in  step 4, and convert it to a UTC-based date and time.
6. Compare the value from step 5 against the value from step 1.  (Alternatively, get a new unix timestamp from this value and compare it against the original unix timestamp.)

Note that you cannot accomplish this task without an understanding of the applicable time zone.  Ideally, the time zone should be a standard IANA/Olson time zone identifier, such as `America/Los_Angeles` or `Europe/Paris`, and you'll need support for working with those within your application or database.  Refer to [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Also note that we do not compare local times, but rather UTC times.  The reason is because the local time *might* be ambiguous, and it's entirely possible the result would be different if you picked the first occurrence instead of the second occurrence, or vice-versa.